# yii2 connect tables in gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-model, yii2-grid

I have main table and several sub tables.

Main table **Product** : *productID / productNameID / productColorID*

and subtables

**productName** : *productNameID / name*

**productColor** : *productColorID / name*

In main table I just insert IDs of sub tables.
And to get normal names instead of IDs I use functions in product Model:

```
public function getProductName()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ProductName::className(), ['nameID' => 'productNameID']);
}

public function getProductColor()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ProductColor::className(), ['colorID' => 'productColorID']);
}
```

If I use only model in view I can write `$model->productName['name']` to get name from subtable.

But I want to create GridView. For this I created default CRUD from Gii. As you know GridView uses SearchModel.
When I did this in list I've got only IDs from main Table. probably because there were no custom functions in SearchModel
I mean there are no connections now with subtables where names are stored.
So how can I connect my main table to subtables in GridView ? What Should be done to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of doing it:
First one is the easiest (I suggest), you can write the name of your relation, and then access to the attribute you need to display in just one string:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'id',

        'productName.name', // Here it is

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Another way (and more dynamic) you can call an anonymous function to show the desired value as follow:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'id',

        [
            'attribute' => 'category_id',
            'value' => function (Product $product) {
                return $product->category->name;
                // make sure your model has productName, or it will throw Non-object exception
                // return $product->category ? $product->category->name : null; 
            },
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

About applying search on those related attributes you can learn more in Yiiframwork documentation [Yii 2.0: Displaying, Sorting and Filtering Model Relations on a GridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/)

And in addition make sure you eager load related tables, so that your gridview won't call a lot of separate queries by using `$model->with()` and `$model->joinWith()` functions